# Python code unstable

Tags: python, import, tkinter, crash

I'm making a program for my Spanish teacher to type in accented letters. The program itself is a autohotkey file compiled into an `exe`, which cannot be easily turned off (I've come to use task manager mostly). The part of the code that I suspect goes as follows (`tkinter` has been imported as `Tk`, and `messagebox` has been imported from `tkinter`).

```
    def stop():
        messagebox.showinfo( "Spanish Accents", "Program Ended")
        import os
        os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM spanishAccents.exe")

    stopSpan = Tk.Button(root, text="Off", command = stop)

    stopSpan.pack()
```

I think it keeps crashing due to `os taskkill` and some way I formatted it, but I can't quite tell. It only starts crashing after either the on or off button has been pressed, but with random timing afterwards. Anybody know what I should do?

Comment: why not using `exit()` instead of taskkill ?

Comment: I would advise using an existing system for typing non-ASCII - all major operating systems have something, I think. My personal favorite is setting up a Compose key - built-in on Linux, and Windows has [a variety of free options](http://superuser.com/questions/64178/compose-key-on-windows).